# I want to see the information beign reference by the feign key in my table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with a table called ticket and employee. In ticket I have a foriegn key called EID that is the primary key for employee.

Employee has other information in it that is tied to EID (fname, lname, phone).

I want to be able to call the row in ticket with all the information and have it display the information associated with the corresponding EID.

Image of table row: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBOHl.jpg

I don't have problems displaying the row with the information from ticket or even displaying the EID. I just want to be able to see the information associated with it.

How would this be done? Would I have to do a "SELECT * FROM employee" along with the "SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE EID=1"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from ticket 
inner join employee on ticket.eid = employee.id
where employee.id = 1
```

Here you can play with it.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/906af/1

Comment: This definitely got me going in the right direction. Thank you. The output I recieved on this though gave me  a second column named EID. I'm assuming this was due to calling the join of the two tables?

Comment: Yes.  When you select *, you get every column.  It's better to say "select ticket.id, employee.id, employee.name" or something like that to get exactly what you need.  If this solved your problem, will you please accept it and/or vote it up?

Comment: I see what you did in fiddle though. You are essentially placing employee.id into the EID column. I will accept answer as soon as it will let me. I would vote it up if I could but it says my reputation is not high enough.